# XmlSerializer in .NET with XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, wscf

Given the following piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerializationTest
{
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.test.com")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public int X;
    }

    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.test.com")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public Element Element;
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var root = new Root { Element = new Element { X = 1 } };
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, root);
        }
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm852"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com">
  <Element xmlns="">
    <X xmlns="http://www.test.com">1</X>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

The question is why does setting the Form property to `XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified` cause the `Element` element's namespace being set to `""` even if it has the `XmlTypeAttribute` attribute with the same namespace as the Root element?

This kind of code (the `XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified` part) is generated by the `WSCF.blue` tool and it's messing up with the namespaces.

Comment: "unqualified" indicates that attributes from the target namespace are not required to be qualified with the namespace prefix. So that's why you get the  xmlns="" if set to qualified its all fine. As u said its from an automated tool. see if there are configurable options in the tool.

Comment: @Aravind: I think that unqualified means that the serializer is not forced to use the prefix (it may or may not). But I don't see why it would CHANGE the namespase of the Element element (from "http://www.test.com" to "")! Unfortunately WSCF.blue doesn't seem to have the right switch for fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can override namespace specified in the element type. E.g. you can have

```
[XmlElement(Namespace="http://foo.com")]
public Element Element;
```

And the output would be

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com">
  <Element xmlns="http://foo.com">
    <X xmlns="http://www.test.com">1</X>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

Microsoft's implementation of `Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified` appears to be exactly equivalent to setting `Namespace` to `""`. In particular, it cannot be used if you explicitly specified any other namespace ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.form.aspx)). If you do, you will get this exception:

`Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'XmlSerializationTest.Root'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting field 'Element'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The Form property may not be 'Unqualified' when an explicit Namespace property is present.`